# Angel Eyes RGB LED Ring Light Wiring Extension

Tags: led, cables, rgb

the cables aren't long enough and I want them to be black. Can anyone please tell me what this type of wire is called? It has four very small cores and runs on DC12V to supply power to four of these lights.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziKV4.jpg

LED RGB 0.52mm Cable 4-Core? How about the connectors? Are they micro JST? I can't find connectors that will fit 0.52mm cable nor can I locate the crimps that must be added to the cable before inserting into the connectors.

The cables appear to be connected to the PCB using super glue (it's solid, unlike hot glue). I was hoping to attach new cables from the PCB but think I will have to attach to the existing cables.

Comment: This is more of a use/shopping question but decide whether you need waterproof cable or not. You may not be able to match the exact color code. If they are RGB I suspect it supplies power + signal to addressable LEDs. Glue looks like epoxy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The cable doesn't need to be waterproof.

Comment: I'm still not sure about what the connectors are and tools needed to crimp these tiny connectors.

Comment: I bought these thinking they were the right size but the connectors are massive: 10sets XH2.54 2.54mm Wire Cable Connector XH Plug Male & Female JST Aerial Docking for Battery Charging Cable DIY from https://m.aliexpress.com/item/4000144108861.html?spm=a2g0n.orderlist-amp.item.4000144108861&aff_trace_key=cf2b0933894a4e97824ea97d2c9251ac-1604076137433-00748-UneMJZVf&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=3089amp-AsZ3jnnTOTVvIYW7_Tt8Gg1604779654394&browser_id=d78cf5663ad34c78896e0620db9a2cdd&is_c=N What size should it be? https://i.imgur.com/mxrvWvs.jpg